# How to open a file system image in php without extracting

Tags: php, tar, ext4

I found a web host that has only two limits for a free account: inodes (how many files and folders you can have) and daily hits.
So I thought I could a cloud storage website thing if I were to put the files in a big tar or an ext4 image.
Is there a way you can access one without extracting ?
Edit: Yes I do need full access to it, meaning read and write.

Comment: I know PHP Zip can extract a single file from a zip-archive [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php), don't know if it is possible with or other archives.

Comment: Do you need like, read/write?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm gonna be using an xml file to store all the "inodes" and a large bin file for the actual data.
Will update on results.

Update 09:41 11/06/2020 GMT:
I think I have settled on an xml structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <empty>
        <z start="4099999" size="42069" />
    </empty>
    <dir name="Folder 1" ctime="1591852715">
        <file name="Shakewhatever" offset="0" size="4087089" ctime="1591852715" />
    </dir>
    <file name="README.TXT" offset="4087089" size="963" ctime="1591852025" />
    <file name="LICENSE.TXT" offset="4088052" size="270" ctime="1591852025" />
    <dir name="Folder 2" ctime="1591852025">
        <dir name="Inception" ctime="1591852025" />
        <file name="Cool.png" offset="4088322" size="8192" ctime="1591852025" />
    </dir>
</root>
```

Right now I'm working on (or at least hoping to work on, I haven't slept for a while) the backend for php, and possibly even python.

End update.